# how come e.target.value is only capturing the first letter in string input in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, input, onchange

The input is only capturing the first letter in the string input. And is that method is correct?

```js
class Example extends React.Component{

    state={
        name:'Ajith'
    }

    changeEvent = (e) => {
        console.log('change : '+this.state.name)
        let name = this.state.name;
        this.setState({
            name : e.target.value
        });
    }

    edit = () => {
        console.log('edit : '+this.state.name)
        this.setState({
            name : <input value={this.state.name} ref = {(input) =>{this.Edit = input}} onChange={this.changeEvent}/> 
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        console.log('render : '+this.state.name)
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.edit}>
                    Edit
                </button>
                {this.state.name}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capturing" here?

Comment: it takes the only one string letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting from the `input` back to the `string` on the `change` event, which is fired for every change to the field in React (not just when the user leaves the field). If you wait until the user's done (for instance, using `blur`), it works. (Or an OK button, or...) Also **strongly** recommend storing just the name, not switching between the name and an `input` for it; just use a flag and conditional rendering. Also note that you don't need a `ref` for this at all.

Some reading: [*Forms*](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) in the documentation

More reading: [*Arrow Functions in Class Properties Might Not Be As Great As We Think*](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1)

```js
class Example extends React.Component{

    state = {
        name: 'Ajith',
        editing: false
    };

    changeEvent = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            name: e.target.value
        });
    };
    
    blurEvent = (e) => {
        this.setState({editing: false});
    };

    edit = () => {
        this.setState({editing: true});
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.edit}>
                    Edit
                </button>
                {this.state.editing
                ? <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.changeEvent} onBlur={this.blurEvent} />
                : this.state.name
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the problem is how the input was written. The function is ok, but you could write it better:

```
changeEvent = ({e}) => { //destructuring 
            const { name } = event.target; // destructuring
            this.setState({
                [name] : e.target.value
            });
        }
```

So, if the function is right, what is the problem? You need to be sure that the input property name has the same value as the key in the state that you want to change. Ex.:

```
<input value={this.state.user} name='user'/>
```

```js
class Example extends React.Component{

    state={
        name:'Ajith'
    }

    changeEvent = (e) => {
        console.log('change : '+this.state.name)
        let name = this.state.name;
        this.setState({
            name : e.target.value
        });
    }

    edit = () => {
        console.log('edit : '+this.state.name)
        this.setState({
            name : <input value={this.state.name} ref = {(input) =>{this.Edit = input}} onChange={this.changeEvent}/> 
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        console.log('render : '+this.state.name)
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.edit}>
                    Edit
                </button>
                {this.state.name}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```